# Frame Errors (Character Stretching) of CP2102N

Tags: rs232, cp2102

When I send a data stream from my PC to a CP2102 USB-to-Serial Bridge, the data coming out of the RS232 side is sometimes corrupted. The receiving micro (an ATmega2560) reports frame errors when this happens.

I send a command of 30 characters every 180ms. for every 10000 commands there are around 15 to 30 failures.

I use 9600.8N1, so a start bit plus 8 data bits should take 0.9375ms. Flow control is set to None.

It is always the first byte and sometimes (1 in 20) the second byte that is corrupted. I've captured the data on an oscilloscope and measured the byte times (beginning of start bit to beginning of first stop bit).

If I have corrupted data, the time is around 1.000ms. Good data takes between 940us and 960us.

It is always the last few data bits (i.e. the highest bits) and the stop bit that is the problem.

See image below for an example of the second byte being corrupted:
[image]

The character between the vertical cursor lines should be a 'P', but it takes 1.000ms and is received as 0xd0 instead of 0x50. The byte before it is a '*' (0x2a) and is fine, it takes 0.940us.

What could cause these frame errors?

Comment: it seems to be running slow when the output is low, is the power supply to the chip stable?]

Comment: What is the clock source and frequency of the AVR? UBRR value? What program on PC is sending the data?

Comment: @Justme The AVR clock is an Xtal and its frequency is 11059200Hz. It's specifically for creating baud rates. The UBRRL is 71 and UBRRH is zero. I've also fed the signal coming out of the CP2102N into a CP2102 and it reports the same frame errors as the AVR. The problem is therefore not the AVR; you can clearly see on the scope traces that the signal coming out of the CP2102N has incorrect timing.

Comment: @Jasen The supply to the chip comes from the USB bus. The chip has the recommended 100n and 10uF caps for decoupling on both the VREGIN and VDD pins, just next to the chip. There is a 50mV ripple on the 5V from the USB. The supply remains stable, even if there is a frame error.

Comment: @NZD which OS? Tried latest drivers? What program sends data and how? Is this replicable with a terminal program like TeraTerm or RealTerm or Putty etc?

Comment: @Justme I am using Win10 and the latest drivers. I use a Python tool that uses pyserial under the hood to send the data. I am in the process of trying to replicate it on another system and/or using different tools. I send a command to the device and wait for a response. I send the next command immediately after receiving the response. If I delay the next command by a few ms then the problem goes away.

Comment: @NZD I just skimmed through the PySerial win32 code the other week. Do you write one byte or buch of bytes at a time? Do you flush the output? It may make a difference. Buffer size may make a difference. Serial timeouts are not controllable unless PySerial win32 code is modified. Anyway it uses asynchronous reading and writing under the hood, so random delays here and there may help.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually found the problem: It is caused by setting the serial parameters while using the port at the same time.

I read the serial port in a separate thread that calls the following method in a loop:

```python
def read(self):
    serstring = ""
    try:
        if self.is_reading_lines:
            self.serial.timeout = READING_LINES_TIMEOUT
            serstring = self.sio.readline().rstrip()
        else:
            self.serial.timeout = READING_CHARS_TIMEOUT
            serstring = self.serial.read(100)
    except:
        pass
    else:
        if len(serstring):
            self.process_read(serstring)
    return serstring  # if called directly
```

I use different timeouts for reading lines (responses to commands) and for reading binary data.

I update the timeout attribute before every read, not realising that this results in a call to method `_reconfigure_port` in file serialwin32.py in the pyserial module.

One of the calls in method `_reconfigure_port` is to `win32.SetCommState`. This is the ultimate cause: This affects the hardware of the CP2102 chip and causes it to interfere with outputting serial data on the RS232 port, which causes stretched data bits.

It makes perfect sense that updating the hardware settings interferes with the operation of the chip, even though the settings remain the same.

I replaced updating the timeout attribute in the read method with a separate method to set it only once and this fixed my problem.